# Prometheus config error: field azure_sd_configs not found in type config.plain

Tags: prometheus

Im trying to add a job in promtheus for service discovery of azure vms.
The job looks like this:

```
  - job_name: 'azure-nodes'
    azure_sd_configs:
      - subscription_id: xxxxxxxx
        tenant_id: xxxxxxxx
        client_id: xxxxxxxx
        client_secret: xxxxxxxx
        port: 9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_azure_machine_name]
        target_label: instance
```

when i apply this and restart the service. I see the following error is syslog

```
caller=main.go:725 err="error loading config from \"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\": couldn't load configuration (--config.file=\"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\"): parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1112: field azure_sd_configs not found in type config.plain"
```

Im running prometheus version 2.15.4 and an ubuntu 20 server

im still confused what that error means or what can i try to fix it.

Comment: I think it's related to indentation. please check previous or next block

Comment: But when i remove this block from the config file everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML parses for me as long as it's nested beneath `scrape_configs`:

`config.yml`:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'azure-nodes'
    azure_sd_configs:
      - subscription_id: xxxxxxxx
        tenant_id: xxxxxxxx
        client_id: xxxxxxxx
        client_secret: xxxxxxxx
        port: 9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_azure_machine_name]
        target_label: instance
```

And, from the same directory:

```bash
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=9090:9090/tcp \
--name=prometheus \
--volume=${PWD}/config.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.41.0 \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

I'm using the latest (`v2.41.0`). There is no `v2.15.4` in either quay.io/docker.io.

I don't have Azure VMs so errors result:

```bash
curl \
--get \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up
```

Yields:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[]}
```